# PC stuck on boot/bios

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bios, boot

A friend's PC is stuck on boot/bios.
When he starts the PC it is stuck on picture #1. Then when clicking ESC it gets to picture #2 and nothing happnes (key clicks have no effect). It seems like the BIOS setting screen is even not fully painted.

[image]

[image]
This is reproducible always.

Some more information:

- Windows 7
- The first time the problem started was when the friend by mistake restarted with a disk-on-key plugged in.
- we have tried disconnecting all USB devices (mouse, keyboard...) but it did not help
- Booting from original windows 7 installation CD does not help - stuck on same place
- When I start the PC I hear the ventilator for a second but then it immediatelly stops and I don't hear it nor the hard drive

What can we do?

Comment: I don't see any pictures?

Comment: my bad, check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it short, it looks like the PC is stuck at BIOS due to it not accessing the hard drive.

However, if it accessed the hard drive and the hard drive gave an error, you'd see that error. If it accessed the hard drive, and it were empty (no/corrupted boot file), then it would say "No bootable device. Insert bootable device to continue."

Comment: I forgot to mention, what do you mean by "disk-on-key plugged in" ?

Comment: a USB disk-on-key was connected to the PC. BTW if this is a hard disk issue why doesn't booting from CD work?

Comment: Booting from CD would only work if CD/DVD drive were given priority BEFORE hard drive and everything else. To change the priority you would have to get into the BIOS settings, which I think you're having trouble doing, correct?

Comment: Try pressing F10, F7, F8, F12, F11 ... Google the computer model and find out what the BIOS key is, and repeatedly tap it while the computer is booting.

Comment: Good News. I tried to find the BIOS key for my model but since I didn't find it I just randomly pressed the F1-F12 keys immediately when I opened the PC and then, somehow, windows started to load.